# Bootstrap Table json from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with ajax and bootstrap table.
I have an ajax JSON I call with this method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax({
       url: 'php/process.php?method=fetchdata',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
           $('#clienti').bootstrapTable({
              data: data
           });
       },
       error: function(e) {
           console.log(e.responseText);
       }
    });
 });
```

My JSON seems correctly but the table doesn't show any record. What am I doing wrong?

Here is also the table definition

```
<table data-toggle="table" class="display table table-bordered" id="clienti">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Cognome</th>
      <th>Data Nascita</th>
      <th>Provincia</th>
      <th>Comune</th>
      <th>CAP</th>
      <th>Indirizzo</th>
      <th>Fisso</th>
      <th>Cellulare</th>
      <th>Note</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

</table>
```

This is also a part of the json that is returned

```
[{"Nome":"","Cognome":"","DataN":"0000-00-00","Provincia":"","Comune":"","CAP":"","Indirizzo":"","Fisso":"","Mobile":"","Note":""},{"Nome":"Federico","Cognome":"Lupieri","DataN":"2015-09-16","Provincia":"","Comune":"","CAP":"34170","Indirizzo":"Via Ascoli 1","Fisso":"00112233445566","Mobile":"00112233445566","Note":"Vediamo se funziona questo"},
```

Comment: What does bootstrapTable() do? Can you provide code?

Comment: seems like a constructor here
http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/getting-started.html
Sorry i cant be more specific but this class is pretty new to me =/

Comment: And you've got no errors in in your console? (jQuery etc)

Comment: Nothing. I use also firebug and in the console i can see only the json called but nothing more

Comment: Can you post a sample of `data` from success function?

Comment: Yeh, does data contain the correct data?

Comment: Sure! i'll edit my question

Comment: Update! the comma is not the end obviously

Comment: do u have all the scripts before your script `jquery.min.js`, `bootstrap.min.js`, `bootstrap-table.js`?

Comment: Yes, all in the head of the document.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SherifAhmedMahmoud/hxumLkhf/181/)

you must specify the `data-field` in each `th` also you must remove the `data-toggle="table"`

`data-toggle="table"` as [documentation](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/getting-started.html#via-data) : **Activate bootstrap table without writing JavaScript. Set data-toggle="table" on a normal table.**

in your case if you don't want to use javascript just do your table as below

```
<table data-toggle="table" class="display table table-bordered" data-url="php/process.php?method=fetchdata">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="Nome">Nome</th>
            <th data-field="Cognome">Cognome</th>
            <th data-field="DataN">Data Nascita</th>
            <th data-field="Provincia">Provincia</th>
            <th data-field="Comune">Comune</th>
            <th data-field="CAP">CAP</th>
            <th data-field="Indirizzo">Indirizzo</th>
            <th data-field="Fisso">Fisso</th>
            <th data-field="Mobile">Cellulare</th>
            <th data-field="Note">Note</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: i have tried your code but instead of mydata in data:mydata what should i put to get my json read?

Comment: same code you have but add `data-field` attribute for each `th` and remove `data-toggle="table"`

Comment: Nothing change but i dont know why. In jfiddle it works. But here it remains white. I'll look for other things wrong

Comment: `data-toggle="table"` wasted my 6 hours 24 minutes today.

Comment: In the jsfiddle, I saw a 404 error in DevTools.  In the console there was the message, "Use POST method for /echo/json, see http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html".  So, to get the jsfiddle to work, simply add, `method: 'POST'`, to the ajax request object.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/getting-started/):

HTML

```
<table id="table"></table>
```

JS

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    columns: [{
        field: 'id',
        title: 'Item ID'
    }, {
        field: 'name',
        title: 'Item Name'
    }, {
        field: 'price',
        title: 'Item Price'
    }],
    data: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Item 1',
        price: '$1'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Item 2',
        price: '$2'
    }]
});
```

This means that you have to specify the columns that will be used in javascript not in HTML. Hope this helps

Comment: i saw this but can i use the data from my json? now i'll try

Comment: Yes. Define columns as in documentation and for data use `data : data` where second `data` is the parameter from success function from ajax

Comment: this code does not work and i dont know why. The title of the table doesnt show up and the data is also not read. Any suggestion?